# Orientations are not applying after a scene having orientation as landscape in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a few scenes one among them should be in landscape mode, for that, I wrote this `ScreenOrientation.LandscapeLeft` in `start`().

It's working fine as of that scene but when navigating to another scene, those all are in landscape mode though the device is in portrait mode.

I tried placing `ScreenOrientation.AutoRotation` to those scenes for which user will navigate after the scene in landscape mode but no luck. Is there any way to keep a particular scene in landscape and remaining all scenes in autorotation mode in unity.

Answer (score 0):

Did you enable possible orientations first ?

```
function Start () {

    //Enable the possible orientations first
    Screen.autorotateToPortrait = true;
    Screen.autorotateToLandscapeLeft = true;

    //then put it to auto
    Screen.orientation = ScreenOrientation.AutoRotation;
}
```

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ScreenOrientation.AutoRotation.html

Comment: Thank you @Jax297,I solved my issue by placing Screen.orientation = ScreenOrientation.AutoRotation; in the same scene before navigating to another scene and it is working for me.